# URL can't contain control characters - Python

Tags: python, python-requests, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to use the Microsoft Academic API and to a run code from their site using Python but my code keeps throwing `InvalidURL: URL can't contain control characters`.

This is the the URL which works in browser:
`https://api.labs.cognitive.microsoft.com/academic/v1.0/evaluate?expr= Composite(AA.AuN=='jaime teevan')&count=2&attributes=Ti,Y,CC,AA.AuN,AA.AuId&subscription-key=<subscription_key>`
(The above call is an example on :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/academic-services/project-academic-knowledge/reference-evaluate-method)

I am trying to call the same example using the below code but its working:

```
headers = {
    # Request headers
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': '<KEY>',
}

params = urllib.parse.urlencode({
    # Request parameters
    'complete': '0',
    'count': '1'
})


    try:
    conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection('api.labs.cognitive.microsoft.com')
    conn.request("GET", "/academic/v1.0/evaluate?expr=Composite(AA.AuN==jaime teevan)&count=2&attributes=Ti,Y,CC,AA.AuN,AA.AuId", headers)
    response = conn.getresponse()
    data = response.read()
    print(data)
    conn.close()
except Exception as e:
    raise e
```

It throws the following error:

```
InvalidURL: URL can't contain control characters. '/academic/v1.0/evaluate?expr=Composite(AA.AuN==jaime teevan)&count=2&attributes=Ti,Y,CC,AA.AuN,AA.AuId' (found at least ' ')
```

Can someone please help me with what I am missing?

Comment: I think it's counting "space" as a control char?

Comment: At the top you write `expr= Composite(AA.AuN=='jaime teevan'` while in the example you write `expr=Composite(AA.AuN==jaime teevan`. Note the missing space and the `'`. Is this intentional?

Comment: @thlik even with `'jaime teevan'` it throws an error. What "space" do you mean?

Comment: @silent_dev there's a space after `expr=`. I'll post as an answer for readability

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Single quotes, spaces and other characters can be troublesome when passing them on an URL. After slowing down a bit, how about if you try using "requests" instead?:

```
import requests

headers = {
    # Request headers
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': '<KEY>',
}

url = "https://api.labs.cognitive.microsoft.com/academic/v1.0/evaluate?expr=Composite(AA.AuN==jaime teevan)&count=2&attributes=Ti,Y,CC,AA.AuN,AA.AuId" 
response = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers)
print(response.content)
```

I just tested it and got a 401 error message, meaning that the request went through but I'm lacking authorization.

Comment: throws `TypeError: can't concat str to bytes` :(

Comment: In that case, try this instead `conn.request("GET",bytes(url, "utf-8"), headers)`

Comment: thanks but `TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object`

Comment: Updated the answer @silent_dev

Comment: `"ClassName":"System.AggregateException","Message":"One or more errors occurred."` Why does Microsoft has to make everything so hard

Comment: In the documentation you link, the request is as follows:
`https://api.labs.cognitive.microsoft.com/academic/v1.0/evaluate?expr=
Composite(AA.AuN=='jaime teevan')&count=2&attributes=Ti,Y,CC,AA.AuN,AA.AuId&subscription-key=<subscription_key>`
That's a GET, we already nailed that down. But note that you lack the `subscription-key` item. That's a query parameter and it goes in the GET URL as well.

Comment: Bingo that worked! Should have seen that myself, sorry. Thanks @thlik

Answer (score 0):

Use raw string (r"myurl")as follows and post if it works:

> conn.request("GET", r"/academic/v1.0/evaluate?expr=Composite(AA.AuN==jaime teevan)&count=2&attributes=Ti,Y,CC,AA.AuN,AA.AuId", headers)